# Did anyone here made a walnut wine?

Tags: wine

Well, i'm curios if anyone here also tried to brew a walnut wine.
I've got a couple of bottles from my spouse's grandma, and this year i've tried to make it myself.
Had a couple of questions though.
What's the time for taking the shells off. And when it will have its сhestnut's colour?

Answer (score 2):

The article linked here suggests getting very young walnuts before you have to shell them; and instead quartering the young walnuts. They also suggest here leaving it 40 days, 52 days or 3 months; so, leaving at least 40 days seems to be a cunning plan.

http://www.williamrubel.com/delicous-vin-de-noix/

I hope this helps.